# Python 2D array i C using ctypes

Tags: python, c, arrays, testing, ctypes

i'm trying to use a self written c lib to proces 2d array from python but with little success.

Here is my c code:

CamLibC.c

```
int TableCam(const int x, const int y, int **Array) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i; i < x; i++) {
        for (j; j < y; j++) {
            Array[i][j] = 1;
        };

    };
}
```

> cc -nostartfiles -shared -fPIC -o CamLibOS.os CamLibC.c

Now here is my python wrapper:

CamLibPy.py

```
import os,sys
import ctypes

dirname     = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
CamLibFile  = dirname + '/CamLibOS.os'

_CamLib = ctypes.CDLL(CamLibFile)
_CamLib.TableCam.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]

def TableCam (A) :
    global _CamLib

    x = len(A)
    y = len(A[0])

    print('x: ', x, ' y: ', y);

    arrayType = ((ctypes.c_int * x) * y)
    array = arrayType()

    _CamLib.TableCam(ctypes.c_int(x), ctypes.c_int(y), array)

    print(array)
```

And my python code where i use the function:

Test.py

```
import CamLibPy
from numpy import zeros

Anum = zeros((3,3))
print('Start: ', Anum)

CamLibPy.TableCam(Anum)

print('Ended: ', Anum)
```

In this test program i try to change all the zeros in the array to ones. but as soon as i try to run this is get the following output:

> Start:  [[ 0.  0.  0.]  [ 0.  0.  0.]  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
>
> x:  3  y:  3
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/media/pi/USB
>   DISK/Test/Test.py", line 7, in 
>       CamLibPy.TableCam(Anum)   File "/media/pi/USB DISK/Test/CamLibPy.py", line 21, in TableCam
>       _CamLib.TableCam(ctypes.c_int(x), ctypes.c_int(y), array) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: : expected
>   LP_c_long instance instead of c_long_Array_3_Array_3

it's saying it expected a c_long but i clearly used c_int to make the arrayType

Can somebody tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `c_long` is the same as `c_int`, but that is not the problem.

There are a number of issues:

- The type of `numpy.zeros` is default float.
- In the Python `TableCam`, `A` is never modified.
- In the C `TableCam`, the 3rd parameter should be `int* Array` and the elements modified by computing `i*y+j`.  That also agrees with `argtypes`, which was correct.
- The numpy array can be coerced to the right `ctypes` type.

Corrected code (on Windows, for my testing):

**cam.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void TableCam(const int x, const int y, int *Array)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            Array[i*y+j] = 1;
}
```

**camlib.py**

```
import ctypes

_CamLib = ctypes.CDLL('cam')
_CamLib.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]
_CamLib.restype = None

def TableCam(A):
    x,y = A.shape
    array = A.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    _CamLib.TableCam(x,y,array)
```

**test.py**

```
import camlib
import numpy as np

Anum = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=np.int)
print('Start:')
print(Anum)
camlib.TableCam(Anum)
print('Ended:')
print(Anum)
```

#### Output

> ```
> Start:
> [[0 0 0]
>  [0 0 0]
>  [0 0 0]]
> Ended:
> [[1 1 1]
>  [1 1 1]
>  [1 1 1]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks mate for the fast response. I tested the code om my raspberry and it works!! You have no idea how long i have been struggling with this code.